# aws life cycle rules to transition files from s3 bucket to Glacier storage class

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli, amazon-glacier, lifecycle

I am creating life cycle rules to move files from bucket to the glacier storage class.

I was wondering if there is an option to copy files from S3 bucket to Glacier using  either CLI or console?

I need to maintain a copy of files in S3 bucket and also in Glacier. Currently I have duplicated the folder in S3. Created life cycle rules to transition files in one folder to Glacier.

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-services-glacier.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made copies of the folder and placed life cycle rules to transition files from first set of folders to Glacier. Based on Tim's comment, It makes better sense to turn on MFA delete and not make duplicate of the folders in S3, before activating the life cycle rules.

Comment: Why would you do that? You're now paying for full price S3 and Glacier. I'm curious what benefit this has. If you wanted to be sure the files couldn't be deleted just turn on MFA delete, or versioning.

Comment: Thats the org policy for the company I worked before. That job is complete now. I will keep that in mind and turn on MFA delete, incase if the customer requires two copies. ty

Comment: MFA delete doesn't create two copies, it just prevents deletion. Versioning can create two copies, but you can delete old copies using lifecycle rules. Copying from S3 to another copy in S3 and making the copy glacier storage class is really quite weird. You're paying full price for the standard class, and paying again for the archived version.

Comment: Tim, I understand MFA is for multi factor authentication, not create 2 copies. version only keeps the differences. The point I was making is, if I had MFA enabled, then I could have used life cycle rules to to transition files to Glacier and still keep a copy in S3 and prevent it from getting deleted.

Comment: S3 versioning I think keeps copies of files, it's not block based / incremental like EBS snapshots. Your second sentence about having MFA enabled and using life cycle rules to transition files to glacier / keep a copy in S3 doesn't seem to make sense - if you transition a file it changes to the new tier, and you've said S3 glacier class not AWS Glacier. You can transition to Glacier storage tier, not the glacier service.

Comment: I meant glacier storage tier, not glacier service.

Comment: You can't have lifecycle rules on a MFA Delete bucket

Answer (score 3):

Your question is somewhat ambiguous. Do you mean you are "transitioning objects from S3 standard class to S3 glacier class", or are you copying them from S3 to the standalone Glacier service? Glacier standalone IMHO is somewhat legacy and doesn't seem to get updates. You also mentioned "copy files" - you don't typically copy files to change their storage class, you transition their storage class. Can you please edit your question to be more precise.

To answer your last question though, yes you can transition an object from S3 standard to S3 glacier class using the GUI. You click the object, select the properties tab, then click storage storage class, the click the current storage class. That gives you the option to change it. There will be an API call, but I don't know what it is without researching it. Google will find it if you search for something like "AWS S3 API change object storage class".

Comment: ty, I know we could transition objects from S3 standard to Glaciar. My questions if there was any way to copy files from s3 to Glaciar and retain the existing files in S3. Currently I have to duplicate the folder and transition the files to Glaciar using life cycle rules when I want to maintain multiple copies.

Comment: You still need to clarify whether you mean AWS Glacier, or AWS S3 Glacier storage class. You can copy anything you like to anywhere, it's a storage tier transition that is more difficult.

Comment: AWS S3 Glacier, I thought there was only s3 Glacier, Whats the difference between AWS Glacier and S3 Glacier?

Comment: S3 Glacier storage class is object based, Glacier service is based around vaults rather than individual files. Glacier is an enterprise service with features few people need, and it doesn't seem to be maintained - it doesn't support deep archive class for example, just glacier.

Answer (score 2):

Conceptually, "bucket" and "glacier" are not comparable options.

The bucket is the object store. Glacier is a storage class for objects stored in the bucket.

You can create life cycle rules that convert objects to the Glacier storage class with minimal delay, or, as noted in another answer to this question, change the storage class via the console.

Comment: ty for answering, I know that. My question was pertain maintaining a copy in s3 while having a transition rules to Glacier